# WKWebView Delegate (decidePolicyFor) issues in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am currently implementing a WKWebView into my application and I want to use the decidePolicyFor delegation method to decide how my app responds to external links.

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {


    if navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationType.linkActivated && !(navigationAction.request.url?.host?.lowercased().hasPrefix("www.example.com"))! {
        UIApplication.shared.open(navigationAction.request.url!, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
        decisionHandler(.allow)

    }
    else
    {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    }


}
```

However the compiler is giving me the following issue in swift 3.0 :-

> Instance method 'webView(*:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'webView(*:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)' of protocol 'WKNavigationDelegate'

Does anybody know the solution to this and more importantly why this is happening

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you find something odd in Xcode, please check [the latest reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455641-webview).
(Some of the references may not be up-to-date, but luckily, the description of the delegate method seems to be up-to-date.)

> **Declaration**
>
> ```
> optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
>       decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, 
>       decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
> ```

Add `@escaping` after `decisionHandler:`.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
             decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
```

Comment: thanks forgot the closure parameter. sometimes the most obvious isnt so obvious uh.